# Mysql update table with max value from another table with inner join

Tags: mysql

```
update cle c set c.dme_id = (
    select max(serial_number) from cle_dme_id a where cast(
        a.dme_id as decimal(7,4)
    )<=cast(
        c.dme_id as decimal(7,4)
    )
);
```

It's not working, and that is the error:

```
Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column '(null)' at row 1
```

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result? which column is *nullable*?

Comment: Make sure you define both tables used in your subselect (`cle c`), because you are using `c.dme_id` in your subselect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the decimal(7,4) was causing the problem. After replacing it with decimal(10,4) it worked fine.